# .remove() not working with function parameter

Tags: jquery, html, parameters

Hi I have the following code with jQuery:

```
function reject(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: api_url,
        data: { validation_id: '11', listing_id: id }
    }).done(function(msg) {
      alert(msg);
      $("'#" + id + "'").remove();
    });
}
```

everything works great except for the `remove()` part:

```
$("'#" + id + "'").remove();
```

which should remove the div where the listing info is, as it was just rejected. How can I make this work?

Comment: Why are you adding extra quotes around the selector?

Comment: I tried with quotes and without quotes and no luck

Comment: oh boy you where right :) thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your selector with additional `'`. It should be just a string representing the selector - `$("#"+id).remove();`